# Rails 4 and Nested Resources with Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am wondering what is best conventionally with nested resources. Per the guide, there should not be more than 1 nested resource and they advice to use `shallow: true` if that's the case.

However, in this scenario, I have:

- A Study

  - A Hospital

    - An Event

In my `routes.rb` I know this is not advised:

```
resources :studies do
  resources :hospitals, shallow: true do
    resources :events
  end
end
```

But this is essentially what I want:

`/studies/1/hospitals/3/events/new`

And it should take a `:patient_id` (the events resource needs it as a field and I don't feel good doing `?patient_id=45` as parameters).

I created a manual resource as follows:

```
get '/events/new/:study_id/:hospital_id/:patient_id' => 'events#new', as: 'new_event'
```

This does it fine and I get my parameters just fine - is this the suggested way of avoiding deeply nested resources?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would break them out so you don've have so much nesting. Like this:

```
resources :studies do
  resources :hospitals, shallow: true
end

resources :hospitals, only: [] do
  resources :events, shallow: true
end
```

As far as sending the patient_id I would send that in the post body as part of the form. Hope this helps.